# How can I set the selected set of c# datagridview cells from a saved set of SelectedCells

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that has a set of selected cells (DataGridView.SelectedCells).  The values are used to filter and redisplay the datagridview.  After the datagridview is redisplayed I want to set the cells used for the filtering back to the selected state.

I have tried saving the set of selected cells and then setting the property back after the filtering is done. However it appears that the SelectedCells property is read-only.

Is there programmatic way of doing this?

Comment: You could try using the cell Indexes (the Row/Column) that each cell refers to.

Comment: Use the [DataGridViewCell.Selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.selected?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Selected);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to reselect them.

Comment: This requirement sounds very strange. And it sounds like you are creating your own dilemma… I am not following what you mean by… _”I have tried saving the set of selected cells and then setting the property back after the filtering is done.”_ … “AFTER” the filtering is done … ? … What if a “selected” cell is NOT included in the filter and how would you know if it was? After a filter is applied, the (before/after) row indexes are meaningless.

Comment: JohnG. What I meant by "AFTER" is to be able to highlight the prior selected cells but you are right row indexes are meaningless. At this point I'll need to find a different way.